# How to add a Div dianamically in count Custom DIV

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I want add a custom div. Here is my code (content-text-para) is one div tag that is repeating so many times . What I want count the div (content-text-para) 5 times after add one div (like : `<div class="my_class"> </div>`) .   this is add dynamically is that possible . I don't want add manually I want add dynamically

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Header & Footer</title>

 
  
  
</head>
<body>

 
 
  <div class="content-text-para">  Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">   Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">   Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">   Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  
  
  <!-- here am count 5 dives here u need to add new dive example <div class="new_gap_div"> HI </div> -->
  
  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">  Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
      
  <!-- here am count 5 dives here u need to add new dive example <div class="new_gap_div"> HI </div> --> 
 
  
  
  <div class="content-text-para">  Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">   Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">   Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>   
      
   <!-- here am count 5 dives here u need to add new dive example <div class="new_gap_div"> HI </div> --> 
 
  <div class="content-text-para">   Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>  
  <div class="content-text-para">    Lijo Mpage exports don't support adding     </div>    
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to add element/s. This is from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

```
function appendText() {
    var txt1 = "<p>Text.</p>";               // Create element with HTML  
    var txt2 = $("<p></p>").text("Text.");   // Create with jQuery
    var txt3 = document.createElement("p");  // Create with DOM
    txt3.innerHTML = "Text.";
    $("body").append(txt1, txt2, txt3);      // Append the new elements 
}
```

Comment: sir is possible to add in my html page sir please check my note i dont want to print the numbers i want add custom div after count same dive in 5 times there add one new div that is my question

Comment: What number are you talking about?

Comment: sir actually i want count the same.   count five 5 add a div like (my-gap_div) than count the 5 same dive add (my-gap_div) than count 5 add dive that is am asking please check my html post also

Comment: In short, every 5 count adds a div?

Comment: check the question am updated the html section with some comment also that is u can understand eassly

Comment: count same 5 dive a than add new dive dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dynDivs() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    $('<div></div>').attr('id','div' + i).text('div' + i).appendTo('body');
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i >= 5) {
      $('<div></div>').addClass('my_class').text('my_class_div').appendTo('body');
    }
  }
}

dynDivs();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try this.

Comment: sir please check my note i dont want to print the numbers i want add custom div after count same dive in 5 times there add one new div that is my question

Comment: @Lijo Mattathil How about this solution?

Comment: sir please check my updated html section only count the same dive than add only one dinamic dive u r print the 20dive dianamically

Comment: Sir I do not understand your english. You will need to revise the code yourself and make an attempt to actually build your own solution. I've given you plenty.